# What are the security risks of using an implemented built-in web browser control instead of the machine default browser?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, risk-analysis

I'm developing a WinForm application using Visual Studio 2015 (.Net 4.5). It's a Front-End with Microsoft Access Database 2016 "In development stage" [I will use Sql Server later in Testing and Production stages.]
At some level, the project uses Google Drive Api v3 and DropBox Api to backup the user's Database in a shared folder.
At first, I was not able to use the built-in Web Browser at all, then I figured out away to do so by :

Implementing the built-in Web Browser Control Class itself :

- Using this Function

```
Public Shared Sub ChangeUserAgent()
    Dim userAgent As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    Dim ua As String = "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
    UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, ua, ua.Length, 0)
End Sub
```

- Then, by using Custom Headers, like this:

```
Dim Headers As String = _
"Accept: */*" & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & _
"Referer: " & "https://www.google.com/" & _
Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "User-Agent: " & _
"My Program User Agent" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
```

**Now, it's working with no problems when I test it as the developer.**
But I want to make sure, before I reach another level of the project, that is nothing left to do concerning this matter. So, my question really is :

> Are there any precautions concerning using the implemented built-in
>   web browser, to consider before continuing to develop my project ?

Comment: Please note that Dropbox and Google disallow the use of embedded web views for processing app authorization flows: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize

Comment: Hello, @Greg , I'm wondering if you are [Greg K.] from the Dropbox Community Help page, Anyway. According to your reference link, it shouldn't be done only because of Google Policy, if a User wanted to use Google Account to sign in. Nothing related to developing Dropbox itself. I'm doing it with Google Drive Api with no problem. But I will dig deeper into this, thank you.

Comment: @evry1falls Yes, I'm the same Greg from the Dropbox forum. Google's policy is one reason, but not the only reason, that Dropbox also has a policy against this. Your app may be rejected by Dropbox if you use a web view instead of the system browser.

Comment: @Greg: Please shed some light on this phrase [but not the only reason, that Dropbox also has a policy against this. Your app may be rejected by Dropbox if you use a web view instead of the system browser], like where does it say so in Dropbox ?

Comment: I'm referring to the production review process ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#production-approval ) where Dropbox will review apps for compliance with the terms and guidelines, such as the documented OAuth flow policy ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize ).

Comment: @Greg [Reference Guide->Did not state anything about using Web-View] , [Branding and Guide-> Did not state anything about web-view], [Dropbox Developer Terms->Item7.2 Termination, Consider my original question is a way to overcome this obstacle, as I'm trying to 'protect my user' as well.]. Otherwise I don't see a good reason why I cannot use an Implemented web browser control, that is why I'm asking my original question after all.

Comment: This Dropbox requirement is documented in the documentation for the endpoint itself ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize ): "This web page should not be displayed in a web-view.".

Comment: @Greg, OK
So regardless to my efforts, YOU ARE CORRECT. Thank you.